# Want to add an CSS class into another CSS class with different property

Tags: html, css

I am using two CSS classes for highlighting the icon color as white and changing the **'h6'** tag background-color as #325868.

**The icon color is by default black in color**. Now, I have actually used a '**.highlighted_fileName**' class for highlighting the **'h6'** element and my icon is placed in a **'span'** tag just beside the **'h6'** tag. Below is my code that I have tried, please refer to the same.

```
.highlighted_fileName{
    color:white !important;
    background-color: #325868 !important;

    .closeTab{
        color:#ffffff;
     }
}
```

```
<h6 class="float-left fileName card elementSelectedId truncate" data-toggle="tooltip" title=` +noOfEditors[0].pathTitle+ ` id="featureFileName_1"
                                style="border-color: cadetblue;  left: 0.5vw; top: 2vh; font-weight: bolder; border-width: thin;" 
                                 onclick="openEditorTab(this,noOfEditors[0].pathTitle,noOfEditors[0].fileName);">&nbsp;`+ noOfEditors[0].fileName +`</h6><span><i id = "icon_1" class="fa fa-times closeTab" style="position: relative; top: 26px; right: 10px;display:block;" onclick="closeTab(this,noOfEditors[0].pathTitle,noOfEditors[0].fileName,document.getElementById('featureFileName_1'));" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

I know this is not true as I have tried it and it didn't give me the result as my expectation.
So can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this. *Also, please refer to the below picture for more information.*

[image: Tabs Picture for changing the icon color into white while highlighting]

Comment: Can you plug in the whole code that you are using for the elements to your post?

Comment: If it's beside you would need the `+` css selector. But please post the relevant HTML so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: Can you please paste html code also. Are you trying to change the color of close icons to white ?

Comment: @SleekGeek yeah, I have added the HTML element code.

Comment: @SohailMushtaqAwan Yes, I want to change the close icon in a white color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add The Following**

```
.highlighted_fileName + span i{
Color:#fff:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not use `!important`. Also for css `kebab-case` is better.
Check this, just rename it as you want, and put needed colors.

```
.label {
   color: #000;
   background-color: #fff;

  .close-icon {
     color:#000;
    }
 }
 .label.active {
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #000;

     .close-icon {
       color:#fff;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), nesting rulesets is not permitted. Thus, your `closeTab` ruleset is likely being ignored.

To address this, simply break out your `closeTab` class from within the `highlighted_fileName` class as follows:

```
.highlighted_fileName {
    color:white !important;
    background-color: #325868 !important;
}

.highlighted_fileName .closeTab {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Depending on the specificity of the rulesets provided by Font Awesome, this may still not work. At minimum, you'll be providing the browser with CSS it can understand. Hope this helps!

P.S. As Vitaliy mentioned, using `!important` should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. I don't fully understand your use case, but I think you should be able to get away without it.